# CSS Code Help Needed

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to find out how to add another box inside my box which would be faded to act as a title bar for that specific box (If that makes sense)!

So basically, in the SOCIALBOX I'm looking to get a sub-faded bar at the top inside which would act as a title bar.

After a few comments of people saying they're not sure what I mean, I created a quick image in photoshop to act as some reference point.

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```css
body {
  background: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg") repeat 0 0;
}
/* CSS MENU BAR CODE GOES HERE */

#menubar {
  width: 98.5%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
.inside_text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  margin: 11px 7px 0 0;
}
.inside_text2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  margin: 11px 0 0 7px;
}
/* CSS SOCIALBOX (RIGHT) GOES HERE */

#socialbox {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 2px solid #126b72;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">
  <div class="inside_text">
    PLACEHOLDER TEXT
  </div>
  <div class="inside_text2">
    PLACEHOLDER TEXT
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="socialbox">
</div>
```

Comment: Before posting a question in StackOverflow you should consider reading [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking for a faded line within SOCIALBOX div, to serve as underline for a title?

If thats correct create another class

```
.title-bar
{
    border-bottom:3px;
    solid black;
    opacity:0.3;
}
```

position with margin-left & margin-top values inside that class based on where you want it within SOCIALBOX.

for example:

```
.title-bar
{
    border-bottom:3px;
    solid black;
    opacity:0.3;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:30px;
    float:left;
}
```

create a:

```
<div class="title-bar"></div>
```

and place that inside

```
<div id="socialbox"></div>
```

BTW make it a habit to use `float:left` when positioning divs with CSS, try to avoid `position:absolute` or fixed, unless absolutely necessary. It just comes out cleaner this way.

Comment: Hello, I'm going to test this code in a second, but I quickly chucked this together in photoshop to hopefully aid as some sort of reference guidance, thanks! http://xomf.com/nlpch

Comment: so it seems like that was the case, this should work, just add width to the class to shorten the length of the line